# Switch to a specific version of Android source code

Tags: android, git

I'm playing with the Android source code and I would like to switch to 2.3.3 and make some modifications from there. How do I do this?

More specifically, I made a git clone of the Launcher2 project and would like to switch it to the `android-2.3.3_r1a` tag. I tried,

```
git checkout android-2.3.3_r1a
```

but Git seems to think I'm trying to make a new branch instead.

I also tried

```
git branch -r
```

which listed

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/eclair
  origin/eclair-passion-release
  origin/eclair-release
  origin/eclair-sholes-release
  origin/eclair-sholes-release2
  origin/froyo
  origin/froyo-plus-aosp
  origin/froyo-release
  origin/gingerbread
  origin/gingerbread-release
  origin/master
  origin/tools_r7
  origin/tools_r8
  origin/tools_r9
```

and then

```
git checkout origin/froyo
```

but nothing seems to happen (files are unchanged) and

```
git branch
```

still outputs "* (no branch)".

Answer (score 2):

all you need to do is `git checkout -t origin/android-2.3.3_r1a`. This will give you the branch you want and track the remote one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git checkout -b android-2.3.3_r1a origin/android-2.3.3_r1a
```

Or:

```
git branch android-2.3.3_r1a origin/android-2.3.3_r1a
git checkout android-2.3.3_r1a
```

Comment: $ git checkout -b android-2.3.3_r1a origin/android-2.3.3_r1a
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches. Did you intend to checkout 'origin/android-2.3.3_r1a' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: What version of git are you using? `git version`

Comment: git 1.7.4.1. Had an older one on my Mac but Macports installed this one and the path is set correctly to favor that one.